# jQuery load page via ajax and post form inside the returned ajax data

Tags: jquery, ajax, dom, forms, post

I'm writing a greasemonkey script to make it so that when a user clicks a checkbox, a page with a form is loaded via .ajax, the form is filled out automatically and then posted.   The form is multipart/form-data which from I've found, can't be posted via the .ajax calls.  To get around this, I did the following:

```
function getConvoPage() {
    $.get("/page_with_form.php", { id: theId }, function(data){
        parsePage(data);
    } );
}

function parsePage(data) {
    var dataObject = jQuery(data);
    dataObject.find('textarea[name="message_text"]').val('Thank you for your purchase!');
    dataObject.find('form[enctype="multipart/form-data"]').submit();
}
```

I am able to set the value of the textarea and I have confirmed that the form is being found, but the submit action does nothing.  I have also tried trigger() and simulating the click() to the submit button.  Neither of these worked, which makes me believe this is just not possible.

What can I do to make this work or what is an alternative approach that will work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add the form to the page in order to post it.  In its simplest form, that'll look like this:

```
function parsePage(data) {
    var dataObject = jQuery(data);
    $('body').append( dataObject );

    dataObject.find('textarea[name="message_text"]').val('Thank you for your purchase!');
    dataObject.find('form[enctype="multipart/form-data"]').submit();
}
```

If you don't want the form to cause your entire page to be reloaded, then you can create a hidden iframe, add the iframe to the page, then add your form to the iframe.  Finally, submit your form, and wait for the iframe's `onload` event (which can be accomplished with jquery's [`load()` event function](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/).

This latter approach might look something like this:

```
var asyncSubmitForm = function( form, callback ) {

    var f=$(form).clone();

    // the form is expected to already have the appropriate `action` and `method`
    // attributes set.

    var iframe = $('<iframe id="tempFrame"></iframe>');
    iframe.hide().appendTo('body');
    iframe.load(function() {
        if( callback ) callback(iframe);
        iframe.remove();
        iframe = null;
    });

    iframe.contents().find('body').append(f);
    f.submit();
};
```

then your `parsePage()` function would look like this:

```
function parsePage(data) {
    var dataObject = jQuery(data);

    dataObject.find('textarea[name="message_text"]').val('Thank you for your purchase!');
    asyncSubmitForm(dataObject.find('form[enctype="multipart/form-data"]'), function(iframe) {
       alert('form submitted. response ['+$(iframe).contents().html()+']');
    });
}
```